# How to change MATLAB display language?

Tags: matlab, environment-variables, locale

I currently have my MATLAB in Japanese, and would like to have everything in English. I have tried most solutions proposed online, but none have been very successful. The following are things that I have tried. Setting environment variables: `MATLAB_LANG=en`, `MWLOCALE_TRANSLATED=OFF`. Inputting this command to MATLAB: `set(0,'language','english')`.

Is it possible to change the default language to English in MATLAB?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on your Windows version, this will help you (from [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/setting-locale-on-windows-platforms.html)):

## Locale on Windows 8 Platforms

Use Microsoft® Windows 8 documentation to open the Control Panel.

### User Locale

1. From the Control Panel, select Clock, Language, and Region > Region.
2. Open Formats tab.
3. Select a target locale from the Format: drop-down list.

### System Locale

1.From the Control Panel, select Clock, Language, and Region > Region.
2. Open Administrative tab.
3. Look in the Language for non-Unicode programs section.
4. Click Change system locale... button.
5. Select a target locale from the Current system locale: drop-down list.
6. Reboot the system.

## Locale on Windows 7 Platforms

### User Locale

1. Select Start > Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Region and Language.
2. Open Formats tab.
3. Select a target locale from the Format: drop-down list.

### System Locale

1. Select Start > Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Region and Language.
2. Open Administrative tab.
3. Look in the Language for non-Unicode programs section.
4. Click Change system locale... button.
5. Select a target locale from the Current system locale: drop-down list.
   Reboot the system.

## Locale on Windows Vista Platforms

### User Locale

1. Select Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options.
2. Open Formats tab.
3. Select an item from the drop-down list.

### System Locale

1. Select Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options.
2. Open Administrative tab.
3. Click Change system locale... button.
4. Select an item from the drop-down list.
5. Reboot the system.

## Locale on Windows XP Platforms

### User Locale

1. Select Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options.
2. Open Regional Options tab.
3. Select an item from the drop-down list.

### System Locale

1. Select Start > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options.
2. Open Advanced tab.
3. Select an item from the drop-down list.
4. Reboot the system.

Actually this trick saved me from Japanese GUI. If you are interested, refer to [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/how-the-matlab-process-uses-locale-settings.html) for more information about how Matlab process uses locale setting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new environment variable ?
There are some instructions on the MATLAB forum [From Here :](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/117490)
I quote :

The default behaviour is for MATLAB to come up in Japanese on Japanese
machines. If you want to use MATLAB in English on your Japanese
Windows machine without changing the language setting in the control
panel, please create an environment variable called MATLAB_LANG and
set this to "en".

### For Windows NT/2000/XP:

1. Click on Settings in the Start Menu
2. Choose Control Panel
3. Click on System
4. Choose the "Environment" tab (NT) or the "Advanced" tab and the
   "Environment Variables..." button.
5. In here you can set (or add) the MATLAB_LANG variable to en

### For Windows 98/ME:

1.add this line to your C:\autoexec.bat file:

SET MATLAB_LANG=en

MATLAB menus will then come up in English.

To get MATLAB help and error messages in English, please type the
following in your MATLAB Command Window:

set(0,'language','english')

To have MATLAB use English every time it starts up, you can put the
above command in an M-file called "startup.m". This file must always
be available when MATLAB starts: it must either be in the directory
in which MATLAB is started or in a directory already in the MATLAB
path. Under Unix, it is commonly placed in the "matlab" directory
under your home directory. Under Windows, it is commonly placed
either in C:\MATLAB\TOOLBOX\LOCAL, or in the directory in which
MATLAB starts. The latter can be set by looking at the "properties"
of the MATLAB startup icon shortcut or Start Menu item (Windows
95/NT/2000/XP right click the shortcut or Start Menu item).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to delete all directories named `ja_JP` from Matlab's installation directory. Those directories seem to contain the translation of resources to Japanese and if it can't find them it falls back to English.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer should be:

```
preference->general->select the language of desktop and error message to english.
```

Change locale is stupid, because it may ruin other program's display.